# Visual Studio Code task regex not capturing build error output

Tags: regex, rust, visual-studio-code

I am having some problems with my Regex for parsing build output from rustc.

The output looks like

```
   Compiling svd2rust v0.2.1 (file:///C:/trust/svd2rust)
error: expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|`, found `Some`
  --> src\main.rs:56:9
   |
56 |         Some("all") =>
   |         ^^^^
error: aborting due to previous error
error: Could not compile `svd2rust`.
To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

My task at the moment looks like:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "cargo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["build"],
    "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "build",
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "(error):(.*)\\s+-->\\s+(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+)",
            "file": 3,
            "line": 4,
            "column": 5,
            "severity": 1,
            "message": 2
        }
    }
}
```

[According to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rAdBF9/1), it looks like the regex should match the appropriate sections.

Comment: From what I know, the `\s` might not catch CR. Try replacing all `\s` with `[\s\r]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pgGndx/1)).

Comment: Try using `.*?` (non-greedy match) instead of `.*`? Also, the dot `.` may be not matching new lines.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-multiline-problem-matcher), you need a multiline problem matcher. This might work; I did not test it:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "cargo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["build"],
    "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "build",
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
        "pattern": [{
            "regexp": "(error):(.*)",
            "severity": 1,
            "message": 2
        },{
            "regexp": "-->\\s+([^:]*):(\\d+):(\\d+)",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct regexp for Rust v1.20.0:

```
"pattern": [{
    "regexp": "(error(?:\\[E\\d{4}\\])?|warning):\\s(.*)",
    "severity": 1,
    "message": 2
},{
    "regexp": "-->\\s+([^:]*):(\\d+):(\\d+)",
    "file": 1,
    "line": 2,
    "column": 3
}]
```